# How to operate CoreData entity data in the widget with swiftui

Tags: swiftui, widget

During the widget development process, I fetched a task list from Core Data and successfully displayed it in the widget. Now, I want to toggle the completion status of a specific task by tapping on it in the widget and synchronize it with Core Data. However, whenever I try to pass the task entity as a parameter in the App Intent code, it always prompts “Type ‘ToggleTask’ does not conform to protocol ‘AppIntent’”.

code:

```
// widgetView
 var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            HStack{
                Text("today's Tasks")
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
                Spacer()
                Image("Widgetlogooo")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width:20,height: 20)
            }
            ForEach(entry.tasks,id: \.self){ task in
                HStack{
                    Button(intent: ToggleTask()){
                        if task.isCompleted == true {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark.square")
                                .font(.title2)
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "square")
                                .font(.title2)
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    Text(task.title ?? "notitle")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(formattedTime(from:task.createTime ?? Date()) )
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .opacity(0.4)
                }
                .padding(.vertical,2)
            }
            Spacer()

        }
    }

// AppIntent
struct ToggleTask: AppIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "ToggleTask"
    
    var task:TaskEntity
    init(task:TaskEntity) {
        self.task = task
    }
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        let context = MCoreDataManager.instance.context
        print("task is toggled")
        task.isCompleted.toggle()
        try context.save()
        return .result()
    }
    
}
```

I want to know how to perform operations on Core Data from a widget, such as marking a task as completed.
This problem has been troubling me for days, and I really hope someone can help me answer it. Thank you very much.